I want to implement a "sticky border" so there is a border along the edges of the page, even when you scroll
I am new to HTML/CSS and wanted to implement a "sticky border" to my page but am unable to accomplish this.


body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pagewrap {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 15px solid gray;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  margin-top: calc(-100vh + 15px);
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  /* height: calc(100vh - 30px); */
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
<div class="pagewrap"></div>
<div class="content">
  <header>
    <a href="/">
      <img id="logo" src="img/Cropped_Image.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
</div>



This is the closest I've gotten, however I am now unable to click on my nav links. I understand this is caused by the higher z-index of .pagewrap over .content. If I make the z-index of .pagewrap to be less than .content, the elements on the page now have priority over the border and phase over it.

What's a "sticky border" and what does "phase over it" mean?

You don't need the extra div, use a pseudo-element and position:fixed


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

:root {
  --border-w: 15px
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  border: var(--border-w) solid gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content {
  padding: var(--border-w);
  height: 1000px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
<div class="content">
  <header>
    <a href="/">
      <img id="logo" src="img/Cropped_Image.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>




Links don't seem to be clickable. pointer-events: none; on the pseudo should do it

@j08691 Yep, that did the trick. TYVM

Thank you very much for the assistance. This was exactly what I was aiming to accomplish.
